# Groovy/Java Google storage auth and request

Tags: java, rest, groovy, google-cloud-storage

Is there any simple code example for Groovy/Java to authenticate and make request to Google Storage. I want to use this API to copy objects from one bucket to another:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/copy

Here is what I tried:

```
String sourceStorageID = "XXX"      
String destinationStorageID = "YYY"

String sourceFileName = "fileXXX"  
String destinationFileName = "fileYYY"

//https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/sourceBucket/o/sourceObject/copyTo/b/destinationBucket/o/destinationObject

String urlToCopyFile = "https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/" + sourceStorageID + "/o/" + sourceFileName + "/copyTo/b/" + destinationStorageID + "/o/" + destinationFileName

RestBuilder rest = new RestBuilder()
def exportFinishedJSON = rest.get(objectsListURL) {}?.json
```

I am getting this response:

```
{"error":{"message":"Anonymous users does not have storage.objects.list   access to bucket XXX.","errors":[{"message":"Anonymous users does not have storage.objects.list access to bucket XXX","location":"Authorization","reason":"required","locationType":"header","domain":"global"}],"code":401}}
```

I know I need to make authentication first, but how ? I read tons and tons of documentation but there isn't any simple example for Java to implement. It's really messy and bloated with so many informations and I am tired of reading and searching it.

I also searched solution with ApiKey and in documentation it says just to append it as param to URL, I tried it like this:

```
String urlToCopyFile = "https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/" + sourceStorageID + "/o/" + sourceFileName + "/copyTo/b/" + destinationStorageID + "/o/" + destinationFileName + "&key=" + myApiKey
```

but no success.

Is there any good simple example of solution for my problem ?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Also tried with different approach like this:

```
if (storageObject == null) {instance.authenticate();}
StorageObject newObject = new StorageObject()
newObject.setName(destinationObjectName)
Storage.Objects.Copy request = storageObject.objects().copy(sourceStorageID, sourceObjectName, destinationStorageID, destinationObjectName, newObject);
request.execute();
```

now getting this error:

```
GoogleJsonResponseException occurred when processing request: [GET] /concierge/test/index
400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Required",
    "reason" : "required"
  } ],
  "message" : "Required"
}. Stacktrace follows:
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Required",
    "reason" : "required"
  } ],
  "message" : "Required"
}
```

Comment: It would be easy in groovy if you use [groovy-wslite](https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite)

Comment: It is not solution to my problem...